# how to deploy permissions of user based on profile through managed package in salesforce?

Tags: deployment

I am creating managed package in my dev org, I am giving permissions of the user to based on profile.

Then how to deploy permissions through package?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link related to your query.It may guide you
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=distribution_perm_sets_profile_settings.htm&language=en_US

Comment: how to giving access to user automaticall in test org to different profiles.